# How to get result from other application using Intent registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult())?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I have 2 application, one application need to get setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK) callback from second application with bundle data. I tried with new approach but not getting the callback to first application. Someone please help.

App1: MainActivity

```
private val getResult =
        registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
            Log.d("Result","${it.resultCode}")
            if(it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                val value = it.data?.getStringExtra("input")
            }
        }
```

Click on button->

```
 val pm = packageManager
  val appStartIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.yourtest")
  getResult.launch(appStartIntent)
```

call above method  `Log.d("Result","${it.resultCode}")` printing Result: 0 RESULT_CANCELED value

Manifest file

```
<queries>
        <package android:name="com.example.yourtest"/>
    </queries>
```

App2: MainActivity
Button click:

```
val resultIntent = Intent()
         resultIntent.putExtra("input", "test)
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent )
```

After calling setResult from App2 not firing getResult callback from App1.

Manifest

```
<queries>
        <package android:name="com.example.mytest"/>
    </queries>
```

Comment: We dont know what you tried.

Comment: @blackapps added the code snippet now. Please check what is wrong with my code?

Comment: App2 has to call finish().

Comment: finish() already calling @blackapps

Answer (score 0):

> > ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()

You shoukd register `onActivityResult()` instead.